# vs2010 publish fails: Unable to add 'app_ofline.htm' to the website

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I've created an online asp.net app using VS2010 with VB. It has been online and working for over a year. It's on our company's public web server but it's only for employee use. For as long as the site has been active and in use, I have had to made periodic changes to improve performance or to fix bugs; no problem until now. Suddenly, though, VS is throwing an error during the publishing process:

```
Unable to add 'app_offline.htm' to the Web site.  The file 'app_offline.htm' already exists in this Web site.
```

The IDE is set up to create the site files in a local directory on my workstation machine, and then I copy the files to the server.

The local directory does not contain the app_offline.htm file, so I don't get why the error is saying that it already exists.

It appears that even with this error, all of the files are being properly created, and the site works fine after I copy them to the server, so this is apparently not a fatal error. But it's still unnerving to me to not know why it's doing that, and why just now when it has been fine for over a year.

I would either like to find what's causing the problem and fix it or to find a way to inhibit the process of creating the app_offline.htm file. Anyone have any ideas? No search has turned up any helpful information.

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried removing the file in question from the project, publishing again, then adding it back and publishing?

Comment: It didn't occur to me that I could exclude the file. So I did that and it works fine now. Thanks! If you'll set that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried removing the file in question from the project, publishing again, then adding it back and publishing?

You can right click on the file(s) and choose "Exclude from project..."

Comment: That did it. Thanks again!